# PDFBox: Highlight text

Tags: java, pdfbox, jruby

I need to add a watermark text into a page and for that I'm using the [example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/AddWatermarkText.java?view=markup) provided by Apache. So far, it is working but one of the requirements is to set a highlight/background color to that text. Does PDFBox supports this or do I need to draw a rectangle around the text? Is there an example of how to do it?

Comment: Must that be (dynamic) text or can be a (static) image ? http://www.kscodes.com/java/add-watermark-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox/

Comment: @PeterMmm dynamic text